# CreateParams(&H2000000) does't work anymore on Windows 10 Creator Edition

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-10

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
    Get
        Dim result As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        result.ExStyle = result.ExStyle Or &H2000000
        ' WS_EX_COMPOSITED
        Return result
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by "doesn't work".  Is there an exception?  Window doesn't get created?  Window is created but behaves differently than expected?

Comment: I mean there is a bug when minimizing and maximizing the form, all controls are invisible. Removing &H2000000 fix the problem, but the controls start to flicker.

Comment: same issue here with Windows10, did you find a solution ?

Comment: Not yet.. how someone find a solution

Comment: 0x2000000 is WS_EX_COMPOSITED, it may be related to how the app itself behaves, not necessarily Windows: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171018-00/?p=97245 do you have a small project reproducing the issue?

Comment: This got broken in "insider edition" versions of Win10.  Redstone2 in particular made sweeping changes in user32.dll, technical debt built up over the past decade getting paid back.  Not the only problem, there were many more on the bug list.  I never heard of anybody having trouble with the release version.  Why users don't upgrade from their preview version is very hard to guess.  Probably a licensing issue, the preview editions are free.