# How to prevent WinForms app from flickering

Tags: vb.net, winforms, windows-10, flicker, createparams

I found the following code which cancels the flickering in a WinForms application:

```vb
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
    Get
        Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H2000000
        Return cp
    End Get
End Property 'CreateParams
```

The issue comes when `"minimizing and maximizing the form, all controls are invisible. Removing &H2000000 fix the problem, but the controls start to flicker"` like it says in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43581224/createparamsh2000000-doest-work-anymore-on-windows-10-creator-edition#comment74259812_43581224) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43581224/createparamsh2000000-doest-work-anymore-on-windows-10-creator-edition).

There's any update or way to solve this?

Comment: I just put a bounty on the [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43581224/832052). If it gets an answer we should close your question because it's basically an exact duplicate. Let's see if someone can answer it.

Comment: @djv Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: @djv No one answered the question after one week. Maybe this is a bug of VS 2019.

Comment: @HansPassant Hi Mr. Nobody :) I was making reference that no one posted an answer, just comments. Now if I must take your comment as an answer then Microsoft is completely broken and VS it's obsolete.

Comment: @HansPassant After a few hours of research I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612487/how-to-fix-the-flickering-in-user-controls). It seems that the person who [answered it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2613272/8933039) (giving a solution) knew what he was talking about.

Comment: @HansPassant Ten years later he answers the same question again but this time without giving a solution to the problem posed. "When a problem has no solution, it's solved", said an old mentor. So I would like to know if would be properly to migrate the entire WinForm application to WPF or change something that could improve the functionality. Thanks for share your knowledge.